# Xmodmap: Six characters to one key?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, xorg, xmodmap

From [OpenSUSE wiki](http://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_the_Extra_Keys_on_the_Keyboard):

> (As long as Mode_switch/ISO_Level3_Shift is assigned to the keycode of Alt Gr - if you assign Mode_switch and ISO_Level3_Shift to different keys, you can assign up to six characters to one key!).

Please tell me the generic steps for getting 6 characters to one कey (k altered to क)?

Answer (score 4):

Put lines like the following in your `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode 0x2D = k K U03BA U039A U0915 U05DB U0137 U0136
```

The keycode can be obtained by running `xev` and pressing the key. If you're starting from a known state, for example, a US keyboard layout, you can use the keysym already assigned to the key, as in

```
keycode k = k K U03BA U039A U0915 U05DB U0137 U0136
```

The 8 columns on the right of the `=` sign successively correspond to the bare key, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and repeat these four with <kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd> as well.

The words on the right of the `=` sign are keysyms. You can find valid keysym names in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` (or wherever your distribution puts `keysymdef.h`); look for lines of the form `#define XK_foo 0xabcd /* ... */`: `foo` is the keysym name. You can also use U1234 where `1234` is the number of a unicode character in hexadecimal (for “exotic” characters like `क`, that's often the only option).

Final warning: there are two ways to configure the keyboard under X. Xmodmap is the simple way. Xkb is another way; it's more powerful, a lot more complex, and less well documented. Sometimes xkb settings can prevent xmodmap settings from working: the xkb configuration can affect what modifiers the xmodmap columns correspond to.