# how to insert unicode characters in xterm

Tags: unicode, xterm

... assuming it supports Unicode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure you've started xterm in a UTF-8 locale, either via the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable or with the `locale` resource (which can be set from the command line). The environment variable method is recommended since it applies to all applications; if you've set  up Unicode system-wide, it's probably there already.

Now, to insert unicode characters... Type them on your keyboard. Yes, really. It's not really xterm's job to facilitate the input of arbitrary characters: X already has features for this. Which of these features is best for you depends on the language(s) you want to type.

- Most keyboard layout for languages based on the latin alphabet have an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to access the third and fourth (with shift) characters on a key. You can even go up to 8 symbols by configuring an [`ISO_Level3_Shift`](https://superuser.com/questions/189869/xmodmap-six-characters-to-one-key) key.
- There are standard ways of switching between alphabets, typically used by layouts for languages using non-latin alphabets. I'm not familiar with them so can't offer pointers.
- Traditional Unix keyboards often have a <kbd>Compose</kbd>, which is the most mnemonic way of entering characters with diacritics and other modifications, e.g. <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> ​→ é, <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> ​→ œ, <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> ​→ unbreakable space, etc. PCs don't have a key labeled “Compose”, so on most Linux distributions the key needs to be enabled explicitly (the “menu” key just left of the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on most PC keyboards is a common choice).
- Going further, and practically necessary to type in non-alphabetical scripts, there are fancier [input methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) such as [SCIM](https://github.com/scim-im/scim) and [UIM](https://github.com/uim/uim). There are several different programs available, and how to set them up depends on your system ([Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/InputMethods), [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/I18N/InputMethods), ...).
- Some editors, such as Vim and Emacs, have their own input methods that you can use with any interface.

If you need an unusual character as a one-off, you can copy-paste it from somewhere (such as [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/), although they don't make it particularly easy). There are “character map” applications, such as [Gucharmap](http://live.gnome.org/Gucharmap) and [KCharSelect](http://utils.kde.org/projects/kcharselect/), where you can browse the Unicode database or search a character by name then copy it to the clipboard. If you want to stay in the terminal, you can use the [`unicode`](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/unicode/) program, which is a sort of command-line-based character map.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer ! I'm kinda surprised xterm doesn't offer an easy way of entering Unicode chars, like vim or gnome-terminal. From Dennis' answer, they're working on it; until it's ready, copy-paste :|

Answer (score 3):

On my system, I can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> and press most keys to get various characters. I don't know of a way to do general character entry. The xterm website [FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html) says:

> Ongoing/future work
>
> popup window that shows hex code for content of a character cell and hexadecimal keyboard entry for all Unicode characters (ISO 14755)

In `gnome-terminal` you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> which will display an underlined "U" then type in the four-digit hex code and press enter. Using `03a3` gives "Σ" for example.

Comment: Getting accented characters with `Alt` is a result of having the “Meta sets 8th bit” resource set (it's called somewhat misleadingly `eightBitInput`). It's a historical survivance from the days when 8 bits were more than enough for everybody and merely going beyond 7 bits labeled you as a weirdo. It's only good for inputting characters 160–254, and even then with a very non-mnemonic layout. Furthermore most applications (basically everything but nethack) expect that Meta sends escape.

Comment: <Ctrl>-<Shift> <u> works very well on Manjaro Linux. I can even create queries against mysql using Unicode chars now.