# Xmodmap: six characters to one key and two layouts?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I know how to have six symbols on one key thanks to this question: [Xmodmap: Six characters to one key?](https://superuser.com/questions/189869/xmodmap-six-characters-to-one-key)

However, when I have two layouts and switch them, weird things happen.
I have the following (well, different, but this is easier to talk about) line in my xmodmap:

```
keycode  31 = a A b B c C
```

When I log in, everything works as you would expect. Pressing key 31 give a, with <kbd>Shift</kbd>  A, with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  c and C respectively and with <kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd>.

However, when I change the layout, key 31 gives me b and B with <kbd>shift</kbd> and c and C with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

This is on Ubuntu 11.10 under Ubuntu. Does anybody undestand what is happening? Could I restrict xmodmap to just one layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41213/what-does-key-to-choose-5th-level-in-gnome-keyboard-properties-do

You need to look into the answer. This is essential:

```
clear mod3
clear mod5
keycode 94 = Mode_switch
add mod3 = Mode_switch
add mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift
```