# Xmodmap configuration

Tags: terminal, xmodmap

On my Debian Linux machine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is bound to a virtual terminal. I can see the corresponding entry by running `xmodmap -pke`

```
keycode 67 = F1 XF86_Switch_VT_1 F1 XF86_Switch_VT_1
```

Per [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/189869/xmodmap-six-characters-to-one-key), which I might add is consistent with what I've read elsewhere, the columns on the right hand side of `=` correspond to <kbd>key</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>.

Given that, I don't understand how the keycode mapping for <kbd>F1</kbd> (above) works for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It seems it should really be either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>?

Here's the output of `xmodmap -pm` on my machine:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x25)
control     Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Can anybody explain it?

Comment: Sorry about that `<kbd/>` mess, neither [I don't really like it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126998/kbd-elements-are-still-intrusive)

Comment: (So, note [the "rollback" link](http://superuser.com/posts/404716/revisions)...)

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit more complicated, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys have typically 5 levels instead of your normal 4. The 5th level can be reached via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>. This allows you to specify the appropriate keybinding in your `~/.Xmodmap` file. Below are some excerpts from the xkb files. For more information about them have a look at http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/node5.html

```
type "CTRL+ALT" {
    modifiers = Control+Alt+Shift+LevelThree;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[LevelThree] = Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree] = Level4;
    map[Control+Alt] = Level5;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4] = "Shift Alt";
    level_name[Level5] = "Ctrl+Alt";
};
```

```
xkb_symbols "fkey2vt" {
  key <FK01> {
    type="CTRL+ALT",
    symbols[Group1]= [ F1, F1, F1, F1, XF86_Switch_VT_1 ]
  };
  ...
};
```